# Why is my approach the wrong method?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The equation $\sin^4x-2\cos^2x+a^2=0$ can be solved if :

My approach was to substitute $y$ as $\sin^2x$ and form the quadratic $y^2+2y+a^2-2=0.$

$D\geq0,$ so $-\sqrt3\leq a\leq\sqrt3.$

Which is not the answer $a²\leq2.$

My guess is that $D\geq0$ can only be applied if $y$ has all real values but I am not sure.

And could an alternative method be given? This is the only method I have to approach these kind of problems.

Comment: Consider $0\le\sin^2 x\le1$.

Comment: Suggestions: 1. Change `sin` to `\sin` to make things look prettier; 2. Your $\sin$ is missing an $x$ (I assume). 3. When you substituted $y$ for $\sin^2 x$, what did you substitute for $\cos^2 x$? It appears you made a mistake in your algebra in deriving the quadratic you wrote down.

Comment: @John Hughes 1-y sir

Comment: "My guess is that D≥0 can only be applied if y has all real values"  Why would you think that?  $D\ge 0$ can and must be applied if if $y$ is restricted to $0\le y \le 1$.  Your method will work just fine.  But you will have restrictions on $a$.  Not just that $a^2 \le 3$ but also that $0\le y =-1+\sqrt{3-a^2} \le 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the quadratic formula you find that
$$\sin^2(x)=-1+\sqrt{3-a^2}\mbox,$$
so first of all $|a|\le \sqrt{3}$ as you found, but you sill have to chech for which of these $a$ you obtain
$$0\le -1+\sqrt{3-a^3}\le 1 \iff 1 \le 3-a^2 \le 4 \iff-1 \le a^2\le 2 \iff a^2\le 2$$

Answer (score 3):

The flaw in your argument is that setting the discriminant $D$ to be non-negative merely finds the restriction on $a$ such that $$y=\sin^2x\in\mathbb{R};$$ whereas the actual goal is to find the restriction on $a$ such that $$x\in\mathbb{R}.$$ The latter restriction is narrower because $$x\in\mathbb{R}\implies y\in\mathbb{R} \quad\text{ but}\quad y\in\mathbb{R} \kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies x\in\mathbb{R}.$$

---

So to solve the problem, first simplify the given equation by completing the square:
$$\sin^4x-2\cos^2x+a^2=0\\
\iff (\sin^2x)^2-2(1-\sin^2x)+a^2=0\\
\iff (\sin^2x)^2+2\sin^2x+a^2-2=0\\
\iff (\sin^2x+1)^2+a^2-3=0\\
\iff (\sin^2x+1)^2=3-a^2.$$
Then set the given restriction:
$$x\in\mathbb{R}\\
\iff -1\leq \sin x \leq1\\
\iff 1\leq (\sin^2 x+1)^2 \leq4\\
\iff 1\leq 3-a^2 \leq4\\
\iff -1\leq a^2 \leq 2\\
\iff a^2\leq2\\
\iff -\sqrt2\leq a \leq\sqrt2.$$